# MSSQL Connection settings for QGIS on Windows

Tags: qgis, sql-server, odbc

OK first lets get the blond elements out of the way- I'm not asking for how I connect to ***my*** actual database.
What I'm asking for is an example or screen shot of the entries required ***when setting up a new connection***.

Nothing I try to do to recreate either my 32 or 64 bit ODBC's is seeming to work and test connection just returns

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unable to connect

Something along the lines of[image: Create a New MSSQL Connection]

*Given that the help files at this point are less than helpful!*[image: help me]
And I've scoured the documentation for instructions in Lisboa, Dufour and Valmeira and the web all to no avail.
It should be so simple but I can't find anything- presumably because everyone thinks it should be so simple!

Pretty please- yes call me a muppet if you want- but this is driving me stark staring bonkers- Can any one help?

Alternatively how the &$^% do I find out more about the QODBC3 Drivers?

because it is rather irrelevant in this case as I've tried it from multiple configurations but nonetheless
QGIS Affected 2.0, 2.2
SQL server: 2008 R2
User environment: Win7 64 and 32 bit tested

Comment: Which Version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/qgis-and-sql-server-spatial-tables-performance

Comment: Provider/DSN parameters not needed if you have a host.

Comment: Mapperz- thanks but no those don't answer the issue- the issue is with both 2.2 Valmeira and 2.0 Dufour

Comment: If the user leave the PROVIDER\DSN: Box blank... the ok button is not active, so the user is forced to fill it up, in order for the OK button to be active... which is confusing to his/her part.. user he/she no idea what word he/she might type the text box!!!

Answer (score 12):

In 2.16... (some really basic information I struggled to find and a note about an unhelpful error message)

The 'Connection Name' is a name for our own use.

The 'Provider/DSN' field can be left blank.

The 'Host' is a DNS name for the server or an IP address and specific port if not standard SQL port followed by instance name where required (eg. localhost\sqlexpress) (sorry - I don't personally undersand this bit - I needed help from the person who set up the database to describe this)

The 'Username' and 'Password' are as you'd expect.
The 'save' checkboxes are to tell QGIS to remember these details.

**Don't at this point click the 'Test Connection' button. You'll get an error 
"Error opening connection: Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"**

Instead, click the button 'List Databases'

You should see the database listed.

Comment: In QGIS 2.18.0 I am not able to open MS SQL Server 8 tables. I am able to connect and list all databases on the connection dialog. Afterwards, when I try to connect, I get:
`[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sys.columns'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sys.types'. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sys.objects'. (...) QODBC3: Unable to execute statement`

Comment: Despite 'Test Connection' being located below 'List Databases', I too tried to test the connection before listing databases and got the Driver not loaded error.  Perhaps a slight UI change will improve the experience for first-timers.

Answer (score 6):

The issue 'QODBC3: Unable to connect' may be due to the configuration on the SQL server. Have your IT Admin 'enable' the Protocols TCP/IP and NamedPipe services for the database instance you are trying to connect to. This is performed in the SQL Server Configuration manager > Network Configuration . Also ensure the IP addresses have TCP Port = 1433 and the TCP Dynamic Ports left blank.

[image: Protocols for Database]

Answer (score 2):

We solve this problem by installing the AccessDatabaseEngine driver from Microsoft:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: Could you please provide more detail with instructions on how to use this?

Comment: You simply install it, restart, and connect in QGIS.