# What are the parameters for my connection QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am new QGIS, I was wondering what the parameters are for the New MSSQL Connection in the dialog window?

Provider/DNS: `? when local ?` tried leaving empty

Host:         `? when local ?` tried my computer user name/server instance name

Database:     `full path to file I assume`

[image: Dialog Window]

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: For host have you tried localhost?

Comment: no, which parameter is that - host?

Comment: provider blank and host as localhost = invalid connection error

Comment: What database information is in your MSSQL server?

Comment: lat/long, address, plus other stuff i hope to be able to ignore

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear :) If you look at the database properties in SQL Server, that should provide the database name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the QGIS help for another type of "New Database Connection" showed these

Name = A name to identify the connection settings.

Provider/DSN = The database server IP address or DNS name (not sure about this I got this from http://tinyurl.com/kjpqm6k)

Host = Name or IP address of the computer hosting the database server (leave blank for local connections)

Database = Name of the database (leave blank for default database on server).

Username = Database user name.

Password = Database password.

[image]

EDIT: In [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/92529/22483) question Mapperz says "Provider/DSN parameters not needed if you have a host."

Comment: My free version would not allow the help function.

Comment: I tried clicking the help for the MSSQL but it said there wasn't one written yet so I just got the help for another type. QGIS 2.4

Comment: Still not sure what goes in the provider/DNS for a local Db, left `host` blank, and supplied the full file path

Comment: I put the server name as I saw it in the SSMS for the provider, left the host empty, still errors.

Comment: This is what a working one should look like http://i.imgur.com/8yc3x9G.png

Comment: @NathanW, purpose that as the answer...

Comment: @ChrisR can add the image to this answer. It was here first.