# "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded" when adding MSSQL layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server

Similar problem as [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332689/driver-not-loaded-driver-not-loaded-when-trying-to-connect-to-mssql-database-i) and elsewhere...

When I try to `Add MSSQL Spatial Layer` to connect to an Azure-hosted MS SQL Server database, I get `Error opening connection: Driver not loaded Driver not loaded` no matter what I try, as shown below. I have never seen the `OK` button enabled. I am using Pop!_OS 21.04 and QGIS 3.22.0-Białowieża (64-bit). Using QGIS on a separate Windows machine, I do not have this problem using the same interface.
[image]

In QGIS under Settings > Options > Data Sources > GDAL > Vector Drivers both `ODBC` and `MSSQLSpatial` are checked. I have tried unchecking one or the other, restarting QGIS, and trying again. Likewise `ogrinfo --info --formats` shows both. I know the host, username, and password are correct because I can use them to connect in Azure Data Studio from the same machine (at the same IP).

I have tried:

- Clicking `List Databases` instead of `Test Connection` (see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/215562/36471)). Regardless of how the form is submitted, the QGIS log panel shows `INFO    Testing connection : ……` and then `WARNING    Error opening connection : Driver not loaded Driver not loaded`.
- Adding a dummy `Provider/DSN` and editing in Advanced settings as per [this](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37427) (`OK` button never enabled)
- Doing `sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev tdsodbc freetds-dev` and then configuring ODBC/FreeTDS with updated versions of [these settings](https://gist.github.com/mdouchin/64f7733a3c4ecfe441f65d5529351a30) in various combinations.
- Providing a full connection string using FreeTDS for `Provider/DSN` that works for `pyodbc` within a Debian Docker container with the same approach: `DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=xxxxxx.database.windows.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE=xxxxxx;UID=kfisher;PWD=xxxxxx;TDS_VERSION=8.0`
- Installing native MS ODBC driver following [these instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#debian17) and then editing my odbc.ini (tried in both /etc/odbc.ini and /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini) with settings based on the QGIS test script [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/.docker/docker-qgis-test.sh#L152).
- Searching QGIS documentation, Stack Exchange, and the internet at large. Unsurprisingly, connecting to PostgreSQL from QGIS is straightforward and well documented, but connecting to MSSQL/Azure is not.

My current odbc files (redacted):

/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini:

```
[xxxxxxSQLServer]
Description = xxxxxx SQL Server
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = xxxxxx.database.windows.net
ServerName = xxxxxxSQLServer
UID = kfisher
PWD = xxxxxx
```

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf:

```
[xxxxxxSQLServer]
        host = xxxxxx.database.windows.net
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.4
```

Comment: I don't believe that there is a "native" MSSQL QGIS "provider" for Linux, but only on Windows QGIS.

I was able to do something similar (accessing MS SQL data) but with a python QGIS script running on Docker Linux with the qgis/qgis image from Docker hub. 
I used an "ogr" data provider with a MSSQL connection string, which uses the default MS SQL ODBC driver that comes built-in with the QGIS provided version of GDAL/OGR.

You _may_ be able to use a GDAL/OGR vector data connection to MS SQL data within the Linux QGIS UI, but I was unable to quickly succeed with that.